# Split a column of a CSV file with a specific delimiter

Tags: python

I am given a CSV file, the first column of which is the index, and the second column is the data which is separated by a space:

```
 1. "1 2 3 4 5 6"
 2. "6 5 4 3 2 1"
 3. "2 4 6 8 10 12"
```

and so on.

I want to make a matrix out of the 2nd column which should look like this:

```
[ 1 2 3 4 5 6

  6 5 4 3 2 1

 2 4 6 8 10 12]
```

How can I do the same in python

Comment: You mean the second _column,_ right?

Comment: @tripleee yeah my bad, fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pandas library to easily read and manipulate csv files

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("PATH_TO_FILE.csv", index_col=0,delimiter=" ",header=None)
```

for more information on read_csv from pandas
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

```
one = [1,2,3]
two = ["1 2 3 4 5 6","6 5 4 3 2 1","2 4 6 8 10 12"]

nested=[val.split() for val in two]
res=[int(item) for sublist in nested for item in sublist]
print(res)
```

RESULT

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12]
```

I've split the list into nested list and then flatend the list.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [pandas library](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("file.csv", sep=",")
data = data.drop(data.columns[0], axis=1)
print(data)
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
6 5 4 3 2 1
2 4 6 8 10 12
```